# Multi-threaded texture upload with D3D11

Tags: video, textures, gpu, direct3d, directx-11

i am currently developing an application which shows multiple video streams concurrently.
The decoding happens part in hardware via DXVA2/Intel Media SDK and in part in sofware via ffmpeg.
The rendering of the decoded frames is done entirely in D3D11 (via Direct2D).

While the hardware decoders produce textures in NV12 format directly, the software decoder has to upload the NV12-formated frames to GPU memory. Since multiple streams (delivered via RTP) are shown, the decoding and upload happens concurrently on different threads.

NVidia and AMD suggest to use a ringbuffer of staging resources to upload data to GPU mem, followed by a CopyResource to a GPU-only texture resource as a fast-path.

The problem is, that Map/Unmap the staging resource (from a ringbuffer) (with MAP_WRITE) blocks
for a very long time (30..40ms, for 720p frame) depending on other concurrent D3D operations.
I tried scheduling the Map/Unmap via a deferred context, but this simply forces the operation to the main thread/immediate context.

What is the best way to concurrently upload texture data with high frequency?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Mapping a free resource shouldn't take 30-40ms.  Are you sure the resource you're trying to map isn't still in use?  You can verify by passing the [`D3D11_MAP_FLAG_DO_NOT_WAIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476183(v=vs.85).aspx) flag and seeing whether it comes back as in use.  Or you can switch to WRITE_DISCARD and let the driver manage the ring buffer for you behind the scenes.

Comment: You are right, when reaching 10 video instances (at 1080p) Map return STILL_DRAWING when using the DO_NOT_WAIT flag. I increased the size of the ring buffer but that doesnt change anything. 
If i dont use DXVA2 decoding, the upload works flawless. 
Seems this is actually related to my other problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625031/dxva2-d3d11video-api-lock-resource-contention-during-multi-threaded-decoding